# Image pop-up fields

Tags: arcmap, popup

Is there any chance of getting a step-by-step for inserting an .jpg in a feature pop-up in ArcMAP 10.1?

You're previous answer in the forum almost got me there but not quite. I'm a GIS student at San Francisco State.  All the tutorials I've seen leave out vital info needed to get 'er done!

Comment: Can you please link to the other post you are referring to?  Can you also let us know how far you've gotten so far?

Answer (score 1):

Short of receiving more information about the question, I think the first place to look for information about this would be in the help file for ArcGIS 10: [Setting HTML pop-up properties for feature layers](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000002r000000)